# From the parent, force an iFrame to redirect the entire page

Tags: asp.net, iframe

My site has an iFrame that displays content from and second site. I don't control the second site. When a user clicks on a link in the iFrame, I want it to redirect the entire page, not just the iFrame.

I've seen solutions for doing this from the iFrame, but I need to do it solely from the parent. I'd prefer to do it in the code behind, but a javascript solution would be acceptable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because of security reasons there is no way to extract any information from another page using javascript and therefore you cannot trigger an event for your parent window.

Comment: The only thing you can do is loading the whole page server side, add event handler to each link and then include it into the iframe. But that really isn't a good solution and it might be dangerous to do as you are chaning someone elses page and offer it on your own page.

Answer (score 1):

If the inline frame is external to your website then I'm affraid as far as I know there is nothing you can do

Answer (score 0):

i've done it before from the coding of the iframe it's self, where any link i click inside the iframe redirects the whole page and not within the iframe....

I used to know how, but now i can't remember the coding... there was a simple target="_top" type answer **(obviously that doesn't work)**